# Access elements in a list

Tags: c#, list

I have generated 8*16 ovalshape's in a form. The code is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        OvalShape ovl = new OvalShape();
        ovl.Width = 20;
        ovl.Height = 20;
        ovl.FillStyle = FillStyle.Solid;
        ovl.FillColor = Color.Transparent;
        ovl.Name = "oval" + j + "" + i;

        ovl.Location = new Point((ovl.Width * i) * 2, (ovl.Height * j) * 2);

        ovalShape.Add(ovl);
    }
}

foreach (OvalShape os in ovalShape)
{
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.ShapeContainer shapeContainer = 
                           new Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.ShapeContainer();
    os.Parent = shapeContainer;
    this.Controls.Add(shapeContainer);
}
```

Now I want access to each ovalshape differently. How could I do this?

Comment: What type is the `ovalShape` variable?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by 'i want access to each ovalshape differently'

Comment: @Oded: `List<OvalShape>` I would guess. `ovalShapes` would have been a better name.

Answer (score 1):

Since `ovalShape` is a `List<OvalShape>`, you can use the indexer to access any one item:

```
var anOval = ovalShape[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already accessing each ovalshape in `ovalShape` differently in your `foreach` loop

```
foreach (OvalShape os in ovalShape)
{
  //...
}
```

Otherwise you can also access each ovalshape by it's index, as

```
var newOvalShape = ovalShape[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already named your controle like ovl.Name = "oval" + j + "" + i;

So , I think you can create dictrionary like `Dictionary<string , OvalShape> dic`

Then you can set it like

```
//...
ovl.Name = "oval" + j + "" + i;
dic.add(ovl.Name , ovl);
//...
```

Then , you can access this dictionary in other methods , and access it by its name.

Comment: i added a new dictionary added as you told.

Comment: i am using 

Dictionary<string, OvalShape> dic = new Dictionary<string, OvalShape>();

but then what? i am not getting access yet/